# VS2008 C++: int32_t num = 0502; // num = 322

Tags: c++

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Express. If I debug  this program, the variable num holds the value 322, even when it's initialized to 0502. What am I missing here?

```
int main()
{
    int32_t num = 0502;

    return 0;
}
```

int32_t is defined in the portable version of pstdint.h Version 0.1.12 as

```
typedef signed long int32_t;
```

Comment: @rubenvb It's not a duplicate - that question is a hint (if you don't know what octal digits are.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

0502 is `octal`, since it has prefix `0`. 502 in `octal` is 322 in `decimal`.

Comment: Right. Thanks. After 10 years of programming, this is the first time I come across the notion of octals.

Comment: I just found this entry about the history of octals and it's use nowdays. Very interesting.

http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/98692/where-are-octals-useful

Answer (score 3):

If you start a integer value with `0` it is considered as an octal number, similarly `0x` is used for hex.